# swapping two text View value when click on button using java

Tags: java, android, textview

[image]

I have created a Dynamic UI using layout param in Java and I want to change two text view value when clicking on image view.

```
public class Sorting_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  LinearLayout Sorting_Linear;
  private final Context mContext = Sorting_Activity.this;
  String[] outletname = {"kevan", "parth", "keyur", "k", "a"};
  Button submit;

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams nametxt = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 160, 3);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams imagebtnup = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, 0, 2);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams imagebtndown = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, 0, 2);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearlayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 160, 1);


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sorting_);

    //==========================================================
    //  Dynamic Designing Code
    //==========================================================

    nametxt.setMargins(4, 6, 0, 0);
    imagebtnup.setMargins(4, 6, 0, 0);
    imagebtndown.setMargins(4, 6, 0, 0);
    linearlayout.setMargins(4, 6, 0, 0);

    Sorting_Linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Sorting_Linear);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    LinearLayout[] llRow = new LinearLayout[5];

    final TextView[] outletnametxt = new TextView[5];
    final ImageView[] imageButtonup = new ImageView[5];
    final ImageView[] imageButtondown = new ImageView[5];
    final LinearLayout[] Linearlayout = new LinearLayout[5];


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        llRow[i] = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsllRow = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsllRow.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);
        llRow[i].setLayoutParams(paramsllRow);
        llRow[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        outletnametxt[i] = new TextView(mContext);
        outletnametxt[i].setLayoutParams(nametxt);
        outletnametxt[i].setText(outletname[i]);
        outletnametxt[i].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        outletnametxt[i].setTextSize(20);
        outletnametxt[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        outletnametxt[i].setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        llRow[i].addView(outletnametxt[i]);


        imageButtonup[i] = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageButtonup[i].setLayoutParams(imagebtnup);
        imageButtonup[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowup);


        imageButtondown[i] = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageButtondown[i].setLayoutParams(imagebtndown);
        imageButtondown[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowdown);


        Linearlayout[i] = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        Linearlayout[i].setLayoutParams(linearlayout);
        Linearlayout[i].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        Linearlayout[i].setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        Linearlayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Linearlayout[i].addView(imageButtonup[i]);
        Linearlayout[i].addView(imageButtondown[i]);
        llRow[i].addView(Linearlayout[i]);

        Sorting_Linear.addView(llRow[i]);


     }
  }
}
```

Here is a full code of designing and I want to change the value of textview when clicking on `imageButtondown` and `imagebuttonup`.

Comment: use temporary variable.

Comment: how i can use temporary variable.

Comment: You can add OnClickListener on both the ImageButtons and write the swapping logic inside onClick method.

Comment: write code of listener in answer of question.@shruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code at the end of `for` loop

```
final int itr = i;
imageButtonup[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int index = itr < outletnametxt.length ? itr+1 : itr;
        String val = outletnametxt[index].getText().toString();//index of text value to get value from
        outletnametxt[index].setText(outletnametxt[itr].getText().toString());
        outletnametxt[itr].setText(val);
    }
});


imageButtondown[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int index = itr > 0 ? itr-1 : itr;
        String val = outletnametxt[index].getText().toString();
        outletnametxt[index].setText(outletnametxt[itr].getText().toString());
        outletnametxt[itr].setText(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: its give a error in below line.    String val = outletnametxt[index];//index of text value to get value from

Comment: variable i access from within inner class error found. @user12345

Comment: what write in replace of [index].

Comment: Do you want to replace with next value or previous value?

Comment: i want give a priority to up and down in my list of name.

Comment: like 1) a  2) b than i want change position of a and b to clicking on image button.@user12345

Comment: its not fully working only swap down  value and not set after swapping. please solve it.

Comment: Can you share more details, how is it working right now? How do you want it?

Comment: when click on up arrow than up text view value set on below text view but below text view value not set on up text view.

Comment: its set a value of both text view  value but its not working exactly with up and down arrow ex 1)a 2)b 3)c i clicking on c than effect come in a and b value please fix it. thanks.

Comment: Do you want to go to first vaue on up if it is at last value ?

Comment: no i just want swap a and b . a and b take from previous ex.

Comment: can you share the screenshot?

Comment: how can i share screenshot?

Comment: Upload image online and share the link here

Comment: i am added image in question i want swap value of text view and change order of text view clicking on up and down image button  .

Comment: If I click down on a, what should happen?

Comment: if u click down image button than change the order of text view. down click value set in below of next text view.